# string must be exactly one character long issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, visual-studio

```
string SqlSelectQuery = " Select * From KTS Where STAFFNAME =" + Convert.ToChar(textBox1.Text);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlSelectQuery, CON);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())

            textBox2.Text = (dr["JOB TITLE"].ToString());
            textBox3.Text = (dr["EXTN"].ToString());
            textBox4.Text = (dr["Direct No."].ToString());
            textBox5.Text = (dr["MOBILE (OFFICE)"].ToString());
            textBox6.Text = (dr["SNO"].ToString());
```

i want to load data from sql server to visual studio by entering the name of the first name for the employee and he's job title mobile ext ....blla blla blla appear in the textboxes and my error is **string must be exactly one character long**

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh MS SQL Server !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should use

```
Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);
```

instead of

```
Convert.ToChar(textBox1.Text);
```

because you can't fit a String into a Char, and the textbox content will be most likely longer than one character

As per @RupeshPandey answer, you're also missing the quote to delimit the string in your query. your instruction should be

```
string SqlSelectQuery = "Select * From KTS Where STAFFNAME = '" +
                        Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text) +
                        "'";
```

Comment: it work but other issue showed up it is showing                                                An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'NAME'.'
:\

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Convert.ToChar(textBox1.Text) requires a single character string, otherwise it throws a FormatException.

Your query should be

```
string SqlSelectQuery = " Select * From KTS Where STAFFNAME ='" + Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text)+"'";
```